# How do I split an array into smaller arrays using a specific character?

Tags: c#, arrays, stringbuilder

How do I split an array of strings using a specific character? this example using '@':

```
string [] stringArray = new string [10];
stringArray[0] = "Hi there, this is page one" //goes into new arrayA
stringArray[1] = "Hi there, this is page two" //goes into new arrayA
stringArray[2] = "Hi there, this is page three" //goes into new arrayA
stringArray[3] = "@" //split
stringArray[4] = "New book, page one" //goes into new arrayB
stringArray[5] = "New book, page two" //goes into new arrayB
```

Comment: Why are you using arrays?  There are much better collection types that are so much easier to work with, e.g. `List<string>`.

Comment: No reason, will look at using Lists instead. If you know how to do it with lists please let me know

Comment: @rory.ap How would using a List<T> help in this scenario?

Comment: @Magnus -- I don't know.  Haven't really thought about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write an extension method which makes use of `Skip` and `TakeWhile`.
This solution is generic which means it will work with any type you give it. Just be aware that for reference types a value comparison and no reference comparison will be done.

```
public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(this List<T> array, T seperator)
{
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var splitedList = new List<List<T>>();
    while (currentIndex < array.Count)
    {
        var part = array.Skip(currentIndex).TakeWhile(item => !item.Equals(seperator)).ToList();
        splitedList.Add(part);
        currentIndex += part.Count + 1;
    }
    return splitedList;
}

string[] stringArray = new string[6];
stringArray[0] = "Hi there, this is page one"; //goes into new arrayA
stringArray[1] = "Hi there, this is page two"; //goes into new arrayA
stringArray[2] = "Hi there, this is page three"; //goes into new arrayA
stringArray[3] = "@"; //split
stringArray[4] = "New book, page one"; //goes into new arrayB
stringArray[5] = "New book, page two"; //goes into new arrayB

var splittedValue = stringArray.ToList().Split("@");
```

I've you have a huge list and you want to do a stream like split you can use a `yield return`. The advantage of it is that when the next item in the list is read the code will only be executed to the next `yield return` statement.

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T seperator)
{
    var items = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (item.Equals(seperator))
        {
            yield return items;
            items = new List<T>();
        }
        else items.Add(item);
    }
    yield return items;
}
```

Comment: I think you should revert your last edit. The answer OP accepted is not this one. I suggest you leave the answer as it was and instead add this new code as an edit after it explaining why you think it is better.

Comment: I think that is better. As I told you, you may add the modified code after this explaining why may be better the use of generics and yield return:)

Comment: @Pikoh What do you think. Is it clear and correct or do I need to clarify some things?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, T splitOn)
{
    var l = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        if(object.Equals(item, splitOn))
        {
            yield return l;
            l = new List<T>();
        }
        else
            l.Add(item);
    }
    yield return l;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using an extension method with `Skip`,`Take` and `yield return` for lazy loading. In second edit i made it use generics to be able to split all kind of `IEnumerables`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> s,T splitItem)
{
    // First we get all the indexes where the string is found,
    // adding the last index of the array
    var indexes = s.Select((b, i) => b.Equals(splitItem) ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1)
                   .Union(new int[] { s.Count() }).ToArray();

    int skip = 0; //variable to know where the next chunk starts
    foreach (int index in indexes)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> array = s.Skip(skip).Take(index - skip).ToArray();
        yield return array; //we return the chunk
        skip = index+1;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(var splitted in stringArray.SplitArray("@"))
{
     //splited is a string[]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If size of your array is not big enough (thousands of items), you can join strings and later split them again:

```
        string new_string = String.Join("#", stringArray);
        string[] combined_array = new_string.Split("@".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] new_array_1 = combined_array[0].Split("#".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] new_array_2 = combined_array[1].Split("#".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The number of items in the combined_array depends on the number of "@". So in general you could iterate through combined_array and get separate arrays.

Comment: You would need to ensure that # does not occur in any of the strings for that to work.

Comment: This was just an example. Sure you need to use specific character, which is not used in ordinary elements.